# Difference between HTMLElement/Node and DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

If I understood correctly, `HTMLElement`, `Element`, `Document`, and `Node` are interfaces at different levels that describes the DOM tree.  For example, MDN says

> The DOM Node interface is an abstract base class upon which many other DOM API objects are based

So it seems we can simply construct an HTML DOM object with

```js
const div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = ...
```

where `div` is an `HTMLElement`.

Then why there exists other standalone HTML parsers such as `parse5` and `htmlparser2`, what additional features do they provide, or am I missing something here?

Comment: So you're asking "how do node.js's HTML parsers compare?" ?

Answer (score 0):

They work in Node.js which doesn't have a built-in DOM parser.

Comment: I see, is there a significant time, memory, or functional difference between these options(i.e. built-in vs third-party)?